# Reply link - Show/hide answer box

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide, slidetoggle

I have a comment section on a website. People can leave comments. Now, I added a reply link to each comment left so that people can reply to a specific comment. When they click on the reply link, the div containing the form for them to answer should show up right under the reply link. This is my code but it just won't work. I have looked online and tried implementing different answers but for some reason I can't make it work.

HTML

```
<a href="#1" class="show_hide"><span>Reply</span></a>
<div class="answer_div">
<span class="answer_text">Reply</span><br><br>
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()" action="/action_form.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="4" class="comment_class"></textarea><br>
<input class="submit" value="Submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
Javascript:
$(document).ready(function () {
var $slides = $(".answer_div").hide();
$(".show_hide").show().click(function () {
    var $slider = $(this).next(".answer_div");
    if (!$slider.length) {
        $slider = $(this).closest(".answer_div");
    }
    $slides.not($slider).stop(true, true).slideUp();
    $slider.stop(true, true).slideToggle();
});
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: I put your code on a jsfiddle and it seems to work fine for me? http://jsfiddle.net/LCfjG/

Comment: wow... now I am completely puzzled. I have 0 idea why it's not working... I will keep checking if I missed something somewhere else.

Comment: Which browser are you using? If you don't mind you could try adding to the fiddle.

Comment: After many many trials, I found what was wrong! It was in a different <td> in the table. I just put the div right next to it and now it works wonders.

Comment: Great! Glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making use of JQuery. So please add the below code between your `<head>` and `</head>` tags in your HTML page and it will work with your existing code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I have it in there. The funny thing is that if I start my javascript code with ".show() instead of .hide()", all the divs will be open and if I click on the link they will close. It's just not working the other way around. Would you know why? My css says: .show_hide{display:block;}. I am not sure what is wrong though.

Comment: Display block means to display the block.  To hide you have to use display none.  Also you can use jquery functions  to show or hide.

Comment: I think this is not syntactically correct$(".show_hide").show().click(function ()